# /customer/account/* showing blank page Magento

Tags: php, magento, error-logging, magento-1.8

I am making a site (in development) and for some reason I just realized that customers cannot login, check their wishlist, my account page and who knows what else. I'm not really sure what is causing this issue or how long it has been happening for which of course makes it a little harder to solve.

The system.log doesn't seem to be showing anything related when in debug mode but I am under the assumption that it is problem going to be a php error somewhere.

The site is running on Magento 1.8.1 with a custom theme from themeforest.

Link: http://bit.ly/1o9KNs9

The above link sort of shows the furthest you can get and then once I enter valid details and click login, bam, blank page.

Has anybody encountered this problem before or know how to solve it?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

EDIT System log:

```
2014-02-10T10:15:37+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 55: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found  in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-02-10T10:15:37+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): -->  in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-02-10T10:15:37+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():    ^  in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-02-10T10:15:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 55: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found  in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-02-10T10:15:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): -->  in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-02-10T10:15:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():    ^  in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-02-10T10:15:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 55: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found  in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-02-10T10:15:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): -->  in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-02-10T10:15:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():    ^  in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

Comment: Please enable exceptiog log AND system log .After that check on excpetion.log and system.log

Comment: In light of your last question posted here, I think you need to re-install your theme or contact the theme provider. The theme will be breaking something here most likely, and clearly it is not installed properly with the issues you have with your missing menu template file in your previous question. Stack Overflow is for asking questions where you have some understanding of the issue and have shown what you have tried to correct the issue and as such it is unlikely that someone will be able to help with the info you have provided.

Comment: Hey @AmitBera thanks for the reply. I thought I had debugging on fully but my mistake. I have just turned it on again and posted the log in an edit above. Does this one make any sense to you? Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Hello @AshleySwatton, thanks for the reply. I know it seems that the theme may have problems but I can assure you that it was fine at a point so I think it is more than likely to be plugin conflicts or things that have gone wrong generally on the way. Also I believe that both of the questions are separate and completely unrelated. Although I thank you for the answer on the other question I have marked it as correct as I found the file in question within the plugin mentioned on the comment section of the other question.

Comment: Alex ,there are in issue on one xml file line 55,which is generaly comment related issue.

Comment: Check the xml file for an ampersand or non standard XML entity. This causes parse errors in the template xml files which is the problem you have. I generally do this by accident by having an ampersand in it.

Comment: They have probably broken because of the formKeys have been updated

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks for all the replys; very helpful. Does anybody know of a good way to located said XML file because I have been trying all day to work out which on it could be with no success.

Comment: Found it by chance :)

Was a dodgy bit of code in filter.phtml somewhere. I shall find it again tomorrow and post it.

Comment: I retract my last statement, I have managed to make the blank page disappear however the login page doesn't work instead it just refreshes. @input the first related post I found was about formkeys possibly being the problem however I have tried amending login.phtml accordingly and it seems to make no difference. Thanks for the suggestion though! :)